# How to retrieve webpage using Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, download, command-prompt

I am trying to retrieve a webpage e.g. http://google.com/ using command line and save to a file locally e.g. google.com_20-06-2014.txt but I need to:

(1) Give custom headers
(2) Be able to use HTTP proxy
(3) Able to use both GET/POST

I have tried using a windows-version of wget but I had trouble with setting and doesn't really seem like a good way.

example:

```
    wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)" --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip" -d http://www.google.com/
```

Is there a better way I can do 1,2,3 on Windows?

Comment: personally I use curl through a cgywin terminal on windows. There should be a curl executable for windows.

Comment: The is no built in command line utility to do this (you could use VBScript/JScript). What specific probs are you having with wget?